# console.log not logging - code for a slotmachine - javascript

Tags: javascript, logging, console, jsfiddle

so im writing this slotmachine code and well console.log seems not to be working im guessing it has something to do with something totally else but hey idno, if you guys could take a look at my code it is here - [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8zg761u/1/)

```
//mappings of lines
//  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
//  b2  b2  b3  b4  b5
//  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
//  ------------------
//  00  01  02  03  04
//  10  11  12  13  14
//  20  21  22  23  24
//  
//  [[false], reels[][], reels[][], reels[][], reels[][], reels[][]]
//  random generated reels
var reel_1 = [
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)]
];
var reel_2 = [
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)]
];
var reel_3 = [
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)],
  [Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)]
];
var reels = [reel_1, reel_2, reel_3];
// shorter version
/*for (i = 0; i < reels.length; i++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
      reels[i].push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
    }
  }
  */// lines that can get winnings
  // basic lines
  var line_1 = [
    [false], reels[0][0], reels[0][1], reels[0][2], reels[0][3], reels[0][4]
  ]; //-----
  var line_2 = [
    [false], reels[1][0], reels[1][1], reels[1][2], reels[1][3], reels[1][4]
  ]; //-----
  var line_3 = [
    [false], reels[2][0], reels[2][1], reels[2][2], reels[2][3], reels[2][4]
  ]; //-----
  // lines starting from first 2 on reel_1
  var line_4 = [
    [false], reels[0][0], reels[0][1], reels[1][2], reels[0][3], reels[0][4]
  ]; //--v--
  var line_5 = [
    [false], reels[0][0], reels[0][1], reels[1][2], reels[2][3], reels[2][4]
  ]; //--\--
  // lines starting from first 2 on reel_2
  var line_6 = [
    [false], reels[1][0], reels[1][1], reels[0][2], reels[1][3], reels[1][4]
  ]; //--A--
  var line_7 = [
    [false], reels[1][0], reels[1][1], reels[2][2], reels[1][3], reels[1][4]
  ]; //--v--
  //    lanes starting from first 2 on reel_2
  var line_8 = [
    [false], reels[2][0], reels[2][1], reels[1][2], reels[0][3], reels[0][4]
  ]; //--/--
  var line_9 = [
    [false], reels[2][0], reels[2][1], reels[1][2], reels[2][3], reels[2][4]
  ]; //--A--


  var lines = [line_1, line_2, line_3, line_4, line_5, line_6, line_7,   line_8, line_9];

  var winning_lines = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < lines[i].length; y++) {
      winning_lines.push = [0];
      if (lines[i][0] == false) {
        while (lines[i][y] == lines[i][y + 1]) {
          counter = y++;
          if (counter > 2) {
            winning_lines[i] = counter;
          }

        }

      }
    } 
  }
  //show winnings

  for (i = 0; i < winning_lines.length; i++) {
    if (winning_lines[i] > 2) {
      console.log("on " + (lines[i].toString) + (lines[i][1].toString) + "X" + (winning_lines[i].toString));
    } else {
      console.log("no win");
    }
  }
```

im not sure what the problem seems to be maby anyone here knows?
I also got this error saying my question is mostly code and i need to add some details well im seeing if  i can create a code for a n slot machine doesnt seem to to be much of it laying around the internet

Comment: a console.log at the start of your code works. Another inside the for loop at the end does not. logging out `winning_lines.length` produces 0, so the problem is in the body of your code and is not inherent to console.log

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at line 79:

```
  winning_lines.push = [0];
```

push is an method, so it should be

```
winning.lines.push([0])
```

Comment: hey thanks :) i editied that but in the meanwhile i changed my code to the better making it shorter and its not working, did you try out the code after your edit?

Comment: @BrynjarHelgiGuðmundsson your code modifications doesnt appear to be in the original post neither in the jsfiddle url. If you talk about my modification, yes, I have tested it and the console message are fired correctly.